# How to create a gradient with 3 colors in CSS without color escalation

Tags: css, colors, gradient, linear-gradients

In this example I have a gradient of 2 colors, alignd to right.

[image]

```
background: linear-gradient(to right, #c4d7e6 50%, #66a5ad 50%, #66a5ad 50%);
```

Is there any way I can have more than 2 colors? For example may I add red color on the right of the second one?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Sure, just add color stops at every (100/numColors)%

```css
div {
  background:linear-gradient(to right, #c4d7e6 0, #c4d7e6 33%, #66a5ad 33%, #66a5ad 66%, #ff0000 66%, #ff0000 100%);
  width: 100%;
  height:64px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: above can be simplified by adding color start and stop together  `linear-gradient(to right, #c4d7e6 0 33%, #66a5ad 33% 66%, #ff0000 66%);`  see [linear-gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/linear-gradient)

Answer (score 4):

You can use multiply background, like this:

```
background: linear-gradient(to right, #000, #66a5ad, #66a5ad, red);
```

Also see this [codepen](https://codepen.io/oldminer/pen/VrqXBo) for much combinations.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer but no doubt it will help someone else in the future...

I have found a good website called [CSS Gradient](https://cssgradient.io/) that generates your gradient color with full control and allows you to copy the CSS code.

This gradient was generated by this website:

```css
div{
width: 100%;
height: 200px;
background: rgb(255,0,0);
background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(30,250,0,1) 49%, rgba(4,0,255,1) 100%);
```

```html
<div>
</div>
```